# how to add stylesheet for separator in QCombobox

Tags: qt, qcombobox

i added two items in a qcombobox with a separator

```
addItem("New");
addItem("Delete");
insertSeparator(2);
```

in order to highlight the selection of item with different style i used QLIstView for the QComboBox view with the stylesheet as

```
QListView * listView = new QListView(this);
this->setView(listView);

listView->setStyleSheet("QListView::item {                              \
                            color: black;                                    \
                            background: white;                           }  \
                            QListView::item:selected {                     \
                            color: white;                                  \
                            background-color: #0093D6  \
                            }                                               \
                            ");
```

now the problem is the separator is not visible at all .. it is showing a empty white space between the items . I'm not good with stylesheets so I don't have much clear idea about how to make a new stylesheet for the separator ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to create a custom `itemDelegate` for your `QListView`.

You can subclass `QItemDelegate` to create your own delegate class. Use `sizeHint` function to set the size of your separator and paint it in the `paint` function. Check if the items is a separator with `index.data(Qt::AccessibleDescriptionRole).toString()`.

```
#ifndef COMBOBOXDELEGATE_H
#define COMBOBOXDELEGATE_H

#include <QItemDelegate>

class ComboBoxDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ComboBoxDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);

protected:
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
};

#endif // COMBOBOXDELEGATE_H
```

```
void ComboBoxDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(index.data(Qt::AccessibleDescriptionRole).toString() == QLatin1String("separator"))
    {
        painter->setPen(Qt::red);
        painter->drawLine(option.rect.left(), option.rect.center().y(), option.rect.right(), option.rect.center().y());
    }
    else
        QItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
}

QSize ComboBoxDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QString type = index.data(Qt::AccessibleDescriptionRole).toString();
    if(type == QLatin1String("separator"))
        return QSize(0, 2);
    return QItemDelegate::sizeHint( option, index );
}
```

Then just set your custom delegate to your `listView`:

`listView->setItemDelegate(new ComboBoxDelegate);`.

Comment: If you don't want to loose all stylesheet support on items replace  QItemDelegate with QStyledItemDelegate