# how to draw a line between items of a QCompleter as a separator?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qlineedit, qcompleter

I have a `QCompleter` and a `QStringListModel` that is set to `QCompleter`. Now how can I draw a line as separator between items of `StringList` that is set to `QStringListModel`. Finally, `QCompleter` will be set to a `QLineEdit`.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can supply your view with an own delegate to this method? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcompleter.html#setPopup

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom model with new type and a custom delegate for your widget in delegate paint you can paint any thing in your new type and allow the default type to paint in parent...
[see this example for combobox](http://www.mimec.org/node/305)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I am trying to provide more details than in my initial hint as I thought that would be enough. I fear that people would start asking further, so here goes it:

#### completerseparatordelegate.h

```
#include <QItemDelegate>
#include <QSize>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QStyleOptionViewItem>

class CompleterSeparatorDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CompleterSeparatorDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~CompleterSeparatorDelegate();

protected:    
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
               const QModelIndex &index) const;
    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                   const QModelIndex &index) const;
};
```

#### completerseparatordelegate.cpp

```
#include "completerseparatordelegate.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QString>

CompleterSeparatorDelegate::CompleterSeparatorDelegate(QObject *parent)
    : QItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

CompleterSeparatorDelegate::~CompleterSeparatorDelegate()
{
}

void CompleterSeparatorDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter,
                          const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                          const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(index.data(Qt::AccessibleDescriptionRole).toString() == QLatin1String("separator"))
    {
        painter->setPen(Qt::red);
        painter->drawLine(option.rect.left(), option.rect.center().y(), option.rect.right(), option.rect.center().y());
    } else {
        QItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    }
}

QSize CompleterSeparatorDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                           const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QString type = index.data(Qt::AccessibleDescriptionRole).toString();
    if(type == QLatin1String("separator"))
        return QSize(0, 2);
    return QItemDelegate::sizeHint( option, index );
}
```

#### mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "completerseparatordelegate.h"

...
listView->setItemDelegate(new CompleterSeparatorDelegate);
completer->setPopup(listView);
...
```

I have not tried to compile this code as I am just writing it on the fly as raw text, but the main idea is basically coming from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828160/how-to-add-stylesheet-for-seperator-in-qcombobox) with minor adaptation.

Comment: what you said is right, but you see, a function named "insertSeparator" is used that I can not use it because I have no QCombobox. what should we do when using a QStringListModel to draw a line

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but here's a "semi-working" solution, which I've just implemented myself.

You need to change the internal item delegate of the completer, either by subclassing QCompleter or just calling the respective functions. This example uses subclassing.

```
MyCompleter::MyCompleter(QObject* parent) : QCompleter(parent)
{
  QAbstractItemDelegate* delegate = popup()->itemDelegate();
  popup()->setItemDelegate(new MyCompleterItemDelegate(popup()));
  delete delegate;
}
```

`MyCompleterItemDelegate` can be implemented like this:

```
MyCompleterItemDelegate::MyCompleterItemDelegate(QAbstractItemView* view)
 : QItemDelegate(view), m_view(view)
{
}

void MyCompleterItemDelegate::paint(QPainter* p, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
  if (index.data(Qt::UserRole).toInt() == SEPARATOR) // this is where you check if the current index is a separator
  {
    QRect rect = option.rect;
    rect.setWidth(m_view->viewport()->width());
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.rect = rect;
    m_view->style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_IndicatorToolBarSeparator, &opt, p, m_view);
  }
  else
  {
    QStyleOptionViewItem optCopy = option;
    optCopy.showDecorationSelected = true;
    if (m_view->currentIndex() == index)
      optCopy.state |= QStyle::State_HasFocus;
    QItemDelegate::paint(p, optCopy, index);
  }
}
```

Note, that this doesn't solve the issue with showing the filtered items with separators. For that you would need to somehow alter the completion (proxy) model as returned by `QCompleter::completionModel()`. I haven't figured that one out yet. Also, you need to somehow tell the completer/delegate what a separator is. In my case I have a custom model. With a `QStringList` perhaps a certain trigger word would do the trick?

Hope this helps someone.